# Confusing verse in "Axiomatic Set Theory" by Patrick Suppes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

While searching for prime ordinals, I found this:

> Goldbach’s Hypothesis is that every even natural number $> 2$ is the
>   sum of two prime numbers. On the basis of the obvious definition of prime
>   ordinal numbers, the hypothesis is false for ordinal numbers. It can be
>   shown that $\omega+10$ is not such a sum.

The definition of prime ordinal numbers obvious for me is *an ordinal $> 1$ that is not the product of two smaller ordinals.* This does not make any sense to me since $\omega+10$ can be written as $(\omega+5)+5$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: $\omega + 5 = 5\cdot (\omega+1)$ (I hope I remember the order of the ordinal product correctly, if not, it is $(\omega+1)\cdot 5$) is not a prime by that definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\omega+5$ is not prime, since $\omega+5=5\times (\omega+1)$.

---

By the way, a better definition of "prime ordinal" would be *an ordinal that can be written as a product in exactly two ways*. With "not the product of two smaller ordinals", $0$ and $1$ would both become primes.